# Introductions to steganography from an information-theoretic standpoint

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, cr.crypto-security, big-list, it.information-theory

Can I get some introductory references for steganography from an information-theoretic standpoint? I recently listened to a talk on it, and the speaker said that he knew of no good introductions to the field besides a few links and papers.

> Kessler, Gary C. *An Overview of Steganography for the Computer Forensics Examiner*. Retrieved on 02/12/2015. www.garykessler.net/library/fsc_stego.html
>
> Hopper, N. J., Langford, J., and von Ahn, L. (2002). Provably Secure Steganography. *IEEE Transactions on Computers*, **58**, 662 - 678.
>
> Hundt, C., Liskiewicz, M., and Wolfel, U. (2006). Provably Secure Steganography and the Complexity of Sampling. *Algorithms and Computation*, **4288**, 754 - 763.

Comment: The list you give in the question includes some excellent papers that should give a great introduction.  Have you read them?  Is there something specific you're looking for that you didn't get out of those papers?

Comment: It's embarrassing to admit, but Hopper and Hundt's work are too high level for me. I don't really have a background in cryptography, but I do want to build a mathematical/statistical notion of steganography without having to read a textbook on crypto.

I get seriously confused when universal steganographic secrecy is constructed.

Comment: What about [Hide and Seek: An
Introduction to Steganography](http://niels.xtdnet.nl/papers/practical.pdf)? Or [this](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/0910/R08/work/essay-at443-steganography.pdf)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a brief overview and introduction to steganography:

Christian Cachin. [Digital steganography](http://www.zurich.ibm.com/~cca/papers/encyc.pdf). In Henk C.A. van Tilborg, editor, Encyclopedia of Cryptography and Security. Springer, 2005

Since you asked for an introduction specifically for *information-theoretic* approaches, you might try this paper as a starting point for more detail:

Christian Cachin. [An information-theoretic model for steganography](http://www.zurich.ibm.com/~cca/papers/stego.pdf). Information and Computation, 192(1):41-56, July 2004.

If you want a coding-theoretic perspective, you might also enjoy the following papers:

Yin Wang, Pierre Moulin.  [Perfectly Secure Steganography: Capacity, Error Exponents, and Code Constructions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs.IT/0702161).  IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 2008.

Pierre Moulin, Joseph A. O'Sullivan. [Information-Theoretic Analysis of
Information Hiding](http://www.ese.wustl.edu/~jao/Papers/JournalPublications/01184136.pdf).  IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 2003.

I do encourage you to also take a look at computational steganography (e.g., the Hopper et al. paper you cite in your question), as many of the powerful results are in the computational security regime